# Wordpress constant-looking translation links / context problem

Tags: wordpress, internationalization, translation

Usually we using original language(en) for translation defaults

```
__('Stop right there criminal scum!', TRANSLATION_DOMAIN );
```

But if translator is another person, and we have a lot of sames strings

```
__('Hi user', TRANSLATION_DOMAIN );
__('Hi anon', TRANSLATION_DOMAIN );
__('Hi or not hi', TRANSLATION_DOMAIN );
```

its important that that person fully understand the context of this string. So I was thinking, can we use some constants like

```
__('USER_PAGE_HEAD_Hi user', TRANSLATION_DOMAIN );
__('DEFAULT_PAGE_TITLE Hi anon', TRANSLATION_DOMAIN );
__('BEFORE_BAN_THIS_GUY_TITLE Hi or not hi', TRANSLATION_DOMAIN );
```

So we make some kind of own language and add additional translation for original lagunage

**Its not a question "how I can do this", only about how good is it or any of existing practice**

*Thanks*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [_x()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_x/) That adds context info for the translators:

```
_x('Hi user', 'used in user page head', TRANSLATION_DOMAIN );
_x('Hi anon', 'used in default page head', TRANSLATION_DOMAIN );
_x('Hi or not hi', 'used before banning', TRANSLATION_DOMAIN );
```